# dynamic list view with check box Issue?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to add checkbox to the dynamic list view which contains the price and text. The list displaying properly when iam trying to add checkbox action it displaying fetal error.

Here is the code.... Please help me out from this problem thanks in advance.

## Adapter class:-

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    class AdapterMenuList extends BaseAdapter {

            private Activity activity;
        ArrayList<AdapterMenuList> objects;
        boolean box;

            public AdapterMenuList(Activity act) {
                this.activity = act;


            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return ActivityMenuList.sub_service_id.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }
        AdapterMenuList getAdapterMenuList(int position) {

            return ((AdapterMenuList) getItem(position));
        }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ViewHolder holder;
                AdapterMenuList p = getAdapterMenuList(position);
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else{
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
                holder.txtSubText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
                holder.ch = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                holder.txtText.setText(ActivityMenuList.sub_service_name.get(position));
                holder.txtSubText.setText(ActivityMenuList.price.get(position)+" "+ ActivityMenuList.Currency);
                holder.ch.setTag(position);
                holder.ch.setChecked(p.box);
                holder.ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        getAdapterMenuList((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;

                    }
                });


                return convertView;
            }


        ArrayList<AdapterMenuList> getBox() {
            ArrayList<AdapterMenuList> box = new ArrayList<AdapterMenuList>();
            for (AdapterMenuList p : objects) {
                if (p.box)
                    box.add(p);
            }
            return box;
        }

            static class ViewHolder {
                TextView txtText;
                TextView txtSubText;
                CheckBox ch;

            }
        }
```

## List Activity.java:-

```
  public class   ActivityMenuList extends Activity {

        ListView listMenu;
        ProgressBar prgLoading;
        //TextView txtTitle;
        EditText edtKeyword;
        ImageButton btnSearch;
        TextView txtAlert;

        // declare static variable to store tax and currency symbol
        static double Tax;
        static String Currency;

        // declare adapter object to create custom menu list
        AdapterMenuList mla;

        // create arraylist variables to store data from server
        static ArrayList<Long> sub_service_id = new ArrayList<Long>();
        static ArrayList<String> sub_service_name = new ArrayList<String>();
        static ArrayList<Double> price = new ArrayList<Double>();


        String MenuAPI;
        String TaxCurrencyAPI;
        int IOConnect = 0;
        long service_id;
        String service_name;
        String Keyword;

        // create price format
        DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menu_list);

            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
            bar.setTitle("Product");
            bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
            listMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
            edtKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtKeyword);
            btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
            txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

            // menu API url
            MenuAPI = Constant.MenuAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&service_id=";
            // tax and currency API url
            TaxCurrencyAPI = Constant.TaxCurrencyAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey;

            // get category id and category name that sent from previous page
            Intent iGet = getIntent();
            service_id = iGet.getLongExtra("service_id",0);
            service_name = iGet.getStringExtra("service_name");
            MenuAPI += service_id;

            // set category name to textview
    //        txtTitle.setText(Category_name);

            mla = new AdapterMenuList(ActivityMenuList.this);

            // call asynctask class to request tax and currency data from server
            new getTaxCurrency().execute();

            // event listener to handle search button when clicked
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // get keyword and send it to server
                    try {
                        Keyword = URLEncoder.encode(edtKeyword.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    MenuAPI += "&keyword="+Keyword;
                    IOConnect = 0;
                    listMenu.invalidateViews();
                    clearData();
                    new getDataTask().execute();
                }
            });

            // event listener to handle list when clicked
            listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // go to menu detail page
                    String result = "Selected Product are :";

                    for (AdapterMenuList p : mla.getBox()) {
                        if (p.box){
                            result += "\n" + sub_service_name;

                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityMenuList.this,  result+"Total Amount:=" + sub_service_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });       

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cart:
                // refresh action
                Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityMenuList.class);
                startActivity(iMyOrder);
                overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            case R.id.refresh:
                IOConnect = 0;
                listMenu.invalidateViews();
                clearData();
                new getDataTask().execute();
                return true;            

            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
        public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            // show progressbar first
            getTaxCurrency(){
                if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                    prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                    txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // parse json data from server in background
                parseJSONDataTax();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
                prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
                // if internet connection and data available request menu data from server
                // otherwise, show alert text
                if((Currency != null) && IOConnect == 0){
                    new getDataTask().execute();
                }else{
                    txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
                }
            }
        }

        // method to parse json data from server
        public void parseJSONDataTax(){
            try {
                // request data from tax and currency API
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

                String line;
                String str = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    str += line;
                }


                // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

                JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0); 
                JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

                Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

                JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1); 
                JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

                Currency = currency.getString("Value");


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                IOConnect = 1;
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

        // clear arraylist variables before used
        void clearData(){
            sub_service_id.clear();
            sub_service_name.clear();
            price.clear();

        }

        // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
        public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            // show progressbar first
            getDataTask(){
                if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                    prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                    txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // parse json data from server in background
                parseJSONData();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
                prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

                // if data available show data on list
                // otherwise, show alert text
                if(sub_service_id.size() > 0){
                    listMenu.setVisibility(0);
                    listMenu.setAdapter(mla);
                }else{
                    txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
                }

            }
        }

        // method to parse json data from server
        public void parseJSONData(){

            clearData();

            try {
                // request data from menu API
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuAPI);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

                String line;
                String str = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    str += line;
                }

                // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                    JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu");

                    sub_service_id.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("sub_service_id")));
                    sub_service_name.add(menu.getString("sub_service_name"));
                    price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("price"))));


                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //mla.imageLoader.clearCache();
            listMenu.setAdapter(null);
            super.onDestroy();
        }


        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
        {
            // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
        }


    }
```

## Main.XML:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@color/header"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtKeyword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_form"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:textColor="@color/hint"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/header"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/listMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lytSearch"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/not_found"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## List_item.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_top_style_1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtSubText"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="aaa"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSubText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="bbb" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="select"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:checked="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Error message:-

```
02-29 08:22:13.848 18814-18814/com.theredandblack.ecommerce E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.theredandblack.ecommerce, PID: 18814
                                                                              java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.theredandblack.ecommerce.AdapterMenuList
                                                                                  at com.theredandblack.ecommerce.AdapterMenuList.getAdapterMenuList(AdapterMenuList.java:45)
                                                                                  at com.theredandblack.ecommerce.AdapterMenuList.getView(AdapterMenuList.java:50)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `getAdapterMenuList(int position)` method. Your are returning `((AdapterMenuList) getItem(position));` which probablhy throws a `ClassCastException` as getItem returns an int which you are trying to cast to an AdapterMenuList

Comment: yes I also know , but i have been  trying to implement checkbox feature with list view , where we can select multiple values and finally add them to a Add to Cart feature. Please let me know if there is work around to this error to implement the above functionality. Thank u. @Niza Siwale

Comment: You casting the integer is causing the problem. Change that line of code and list getItem return a AdaoterMenuList object and not an integer

Comment: I tried it but didn't get the solution @Niza Siwale